# how to copy files in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to copy file from one location to another location using asp.net

Comment: Do you mean over the internet, or locally?

Answer (score 2):

In C#:
  File.Copy(srcpath, destpath2);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.....

```
imports System.io

  Public Shared Sub CopyFlashScriptFile(ByVal SourceDirectory As String, ByVal DestinationDirectory As String)
            Try
                Dim f() As String = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory)
                For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(f)
                    File.Copy(f(i), DestinationDirectory & "\" & fileNameWithoutThePath(f(i)))
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You could actually read the file from one location and write it to another:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145952/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072303-1.aspx

With the correct permissions, you could delete the source file when the write is complete...